# Write dynamic form data to its own line in a file

Tags: php

---

Well I will start over on what I am trying to accomplish.

I have a site where I want to have form that in a "Visitor name" section to be able to add fields as needed. I think I have that worked out.

```
<fieldset>
        <legend>Visitor Name</legend>
<div id="placeholder">
        <div id="addmore">
                <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name[]" value="">
                <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name[]" value"">
                <label for="jobtitle">Job Title:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name[]" value="">
        </div>
</div>
```

and the js code is

```
var _counter = 0;
function Add() {
    _counter++;
    var oClone = document.getElementById("addmore").cloneNode(true);
    oClone.id += (_counter + "");
    document.getElementById("placeholder").appendChild(oClone);
}
```

That creates the fields when the "Add Visitor" button is pushed with no limit to the amount of dynamic fileds that can be created.

So I guess the PHP part is where I am getting hung up.

How do I pass those dynamic values into the php script and place them in a file.

When I use

```
foreach($_POST['name'] as $info) {
      fwrite($file, "$companyname,$info,$boxes,$boxes1,$boxes2,$boxes3,$boxes4,$boxes5,$boxes6,$boxes7,$boxes8,$boxes9,$boxes10,$boxes11 \n");
    }
```

I get

Company,Fred,No,No,No,No,Yes,No,No,No,No,Yes,No,Yes
Company,Williams,No,No,No,No,Yes,No,No,No,No,Yes,No,Yes
Company,Hello,No,No,No,No,Yes,No,No,No,No,Yes,No,Yes
Company,Todd,No,No,No,No,Yes,No,No,No,No,Yes,No,Yes
Company,Williams,No,No,No,No,Yes,No,No,No,No,Yes,No,Yes
Company,Hello,No,No,No,No,Yes,No,No,No,No,Yes,No,Yes

Instead of

Company,Fred,Williams,Hello,No,No,No,No,Yes,No,No,No,No,Yes,No,Yes
Company,Todd,Williams,Hello,No,No,No,No,Yes,No,No,No,No,Yes,No,Yes

So I guess I am getting the data but I need it put in the above format.

Sorry for my ignorance on this.

when I do:

```
$my_array = $_POST['name'];
$visitor = implode(",",$my_array);
```

and then

```
echo "$companyname,$visitor,$boxes,$boxes1,$boxes2,$boxes3,$boxes4,$boxes5,$boxes6,$boxes7,$boxes8,$boxes9,$boxes10,$boxes11 <br />";
```

and have more than one name it give me

Company,Billy,Williams,test,Bobby,Williams,test,No,No,No,No,No,No,No,No,No,No,No,No

to which I get that is is just taking the $visitor array and addning to the $visitor section. So it is getting the data I just still can't get it in a file one line per name.

and when I do

```
print_r($visitor);
```

I get the information that was entered into the text boxes in one line.

Billy,Williams,test,Bob,Williams,test

and when I do

```
print_r($_POST);
```

I get

```
Array ( [companyname] => Buster [name] => Array ( [0] => bob [1] => Buddy [2] => Test [3] => bob [4] => Buddy [5] => Test ) [Submit] => Add Visitor )
```

I figured this out.

```
foreach($firstname as $key => $value){
fwrite($file, "$companyname,$value,$lastname[$key],$jobtitle[$key],$boxes,$boxes1,$boxes2,$boxes3,$boxes4,$boxes5,$boxes6,$boxes7,$boxes8,$boxes9,$boxes10,$boxes11 \n");
```

Comment: Can you show the code that's writing to the file? which is where you have your problem?

Comment: I added some of that to my post.

Comment: @rantsh I think I added the code in my post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did to fix my issue

```
foreach($firstname as $key => $value){
fwrite($file, "$companyname,$value,$lastname[$key],$jobtitle[$key],$boxes,$boxes1,$boxes2,$boxes3,$boxes4,$boxes5,$boxes6,$boxes7,$boxes8,$boxes9,$boxes10,$boxes11 \n");
```

I put this in my original post but figure I would post this as the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can pass the data into an array and it writes t file, read up how to use the PHP fputcsv() here and see how it helps you. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

example from the url above:

```
<?php

$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: What if I don't know the array values?

Comment: From your earlier post before you edited it, you said you were getting the arrays then came my reply. If you don't know what the exact values are you can use print_r() or var_dump() to find out what values existed and at what string.

Comment: Well I get the data because I get a file as listed above. But I have not been able to get the dynamic fileds to pass together in groups. Like First Name, Last Name, Job title. I may reedit my post and see if I can do a better job at explaning what I need done. Thanks OmniPotens

Comment: I changed my original post with some output from print_r() and what have you.

Comment: I'd like us to get into a chat with this so we can narrow down the issue gradually then post a final answer here because you've modified your question so many times. Give me a time when you'll be available then we get on chat and get this settled

Comment: I will be available in a couple hours. I was hoping I cleaned my post up. Same information and I did add the js that was doing the adding of the fields.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to get back to you on this. I already figured out your weren't adding values to your array something like foreach($a as $key => $value){ echo "this is ".$key." and this is ".$value; }. This would have solved it long ago. Sorry once again for late attention.

Comment: No worries friend. I am just glad I figured it out. This site is very helpful resource, and I have found answers to many questions just by searching.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking at @OmniPotents answer, another quick and [very] dirty option is:

```
$a = array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd');
$b = array('zzz', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd');

function toCsv($arr) {
    return file_put_contents('file.csv', implode(",", $arr) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
} 

toCsv($a);
toCsv($b);
```

Then file.csv would look like

```
aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd
zzz,bbb,ccc,dddd
```

Keep in mind that such a solution is not taking into consideration stuff like text delimiters which are important for certain CSVs